# Can't access an NSMutableArray created with Json in another object

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

I create an NSMutableArray:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *components = [parser objectWithString:@"[\"Item1\",\"Item2\"]"];
```

then I access it from the same method: no problem!
Then I try to access it from another object: crash!!??
It doesn't happen if i create the NSMutableArray with other means (e.g. initWithObjects:)

Any clue?
It's been all day I can't find a solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array returned from `[parser objectWithString:]` is autoreleased; you need to `retain` it yourself if you want to keep it around.

(You're also probably leaking `parser` unless you're releasing it later in your method.)